# Java Cast from Object to long to String

Tags: java, string, object, casting, long-integer

Here's the situation, I have an Object in a Map which I explicitly know to contain an instance of Long and I need to turn that value into a string but keep getting incompatible type errors. Here's what my code looks like:

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...;
Object obj = new Long(31415L);
String str = Long.valueOf((long)map.get("id")); //Problem line
```

This gives:

```
Inconvertible types.
Found   : java.lang.Object
Required: long
```

Any suggestions as to how to get around this?

Comment: You need to cast to a (Long) not a (long).  Primitives are not castable to Objects

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Was mistaken because the method Long.valueOf needed a primitive so I was tried to do that XD Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do

```
String str = map.get("id").toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use, for instance:

```
String.valueOf(map.get("id"))
```

The problem is that you try and cast an object to a primitive type. That cannot work.

But since the values of your map will be `Long`s anyway (collections cannot contain primitive types, save for specialized implementations such as found in GNU Trove), look at @BheshGurung's answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can use the toString function;  

 public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(map.get("id"))
 }



    String str = map.get("id").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues here:

1. You created a **L**ong, not a **l**ong.  Therefore you need to cast back to a **L**ong, not a **l**ong.
2. In order to get the String representation of a **L**ong you must call toString() on it.

Use this:
`String str = ((Long)map.get("id")).toString();`